# How can I access the body from HTTP delete in Flask?

Tags: python, angularjs, rest, flask

I have this method in my Flask WEB API, that receive a list of IDs.

```
@app.route("/delete_item", methods=['DELETE'])
def delete_item():
    items = request.get_json()
    print(items)
    my_class.delete(items)
    return make_response()
```

When I call this method, the request.get_json() return None.
I am calling it using AngularJS, as bellow:

```
var data = ['0', '1'. '2']
$http.delete('base_url/delete_item', {data});
```

How can I access the body in delete http request?
The others methods (GET, PUT and POST) are working well.

Comment: It's not uncommon for web servers to ignore the body for methods GET, DELETE, OPTIONS and HEAD. I'm not sure exactly what the http specs says, but it's more common to send a DELETE for each resource you want to destroy. `$http.delete('base_url/items/1/')` or try to POST to `base_url/delete_item`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the [docs](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/) say:

`get_json(force=False, silent=False, cache=True)`

"Parses the incoming JSON request data and returns it. By default this function will return None if the mimetype is not application/json but this can be overridden by the force parameter. If parsing fails the on_json_loading_failed() method on the request object will be invoked."

So from this you will either have to:

1. Set mimetype to `applicatation/json`
2. Set the force parameter to true